# How to sandbox Chromium that's installed via SNAP?

Tags: permissions, security, chromium, snap, firejail

In Ubuntu 19.04, you can install Chromium using [snap](https://snapcraft.io/chromium) like this:

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

However, when installing Chromium via snap, you **cannot** sandbox it with [firejail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/firejail.1.html) like this:

```
firejail chromium-browser
```

The command above runs the *non-snap* version of chromium in a sandbox where chromium only has access to the *Downloads* folder (and not your entire home folder).

However, when Chromium is install as a SNAP, firejail cannot achieve these file system restrictions. When you use Chromium installed via `sudo apt install chromium-browser`, firejail works, but it doesn't work with snap-installed chromium.

I understand that [future versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMPTp4Hjbhg&t=710s) of Ubuntu will only be offering the snap package of Chromium, so that's why I'm trying to address this issue right now in Ubuntu 19.04. See [this](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-chromium-browser-deb-to-snap-transition/11179) as well.

I've requested an alternative snap installation method, that only gives Chromium access to the `Downloads` folder [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1847092).

Until then, how can I sandbox Chromium (installed via SNAP), in a manner like firejail sandboxes Chromium (installed via apt)?

Comment: Snap apps should already be sandboxed, but I guess you could try to run them through firejail, if you like. Snap's executables are installed in `/snap/bin`, so try `firejail /snap/bin/chromium-browser`.

Comment: The snap for Chromium is sandboxed to a degree, but not to the degree I want. How can I control exactly what portions of the file system the installation has access to? firejail /snap/bin/chromium-browser doesn't work.

Comment: Look here: https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management

Comment: @ajgringo619 : That looks like a good start. I was able to disconnect the ability to access the home folder, but I'm now trying to figure out how to enable access to the `Downloads` folder exclusively.

Comment: This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206502/256054) shows how to install the Debian repo of Chromium onto Ubuntu/Kubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Firejail would be like using a sandbox inside a sandbox.

[Flatpak](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html) and [Snap](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/security-and-sandboxing) have their own sandboxing strategies. One and the other with their flaws. A lot has been written about (note that some of this issues might be already solved):

- [Flatpak - a security nightmare](https://flatkill.org/)
- [Are Snap and Flatpak apps safe to install? Are they "official", approved or tested for a particular distro version?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1179188/349837)
- [Oh, Snap! Security Holes Found in Linux Packaging System – The New Stack](https://thenewstack.io/oh-snap-security-holes-found-in-linux-packaging-system/)
- [Linux expert Matthew Garrett: Ubuntu 16.04's new Snap format is a security risk | ZDNet](https://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-expert-matthew-garrett-ubuntu-16-04s-new-snap-format-is-a-security-risk/)
- [Ubuntu, does not 'Security Check' Snap packages. - Linux & Unix](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/677386/ubuntu-does-not-security-check-snap-packages/)

Answer (score 2):

According to Firejail's man page which you can access by the command `man firejail`, they do not support snap packages.

> Alternative sandbox technologies like snap (https://snapcraft.io/) and flatpak (https://flatpak.org/) are not supported. Snap and flatpak  packages have their own native management tools and will not work when  sandboxed with Firejail