# Why apt package chromium-browser installs snap package instead?

Tags: apt, package-management, snap

When I do

```
apt-get install chromium-browser
```

it downloads some .deb file, and then installs a snap package:

```
Selecting previously unselected package chromium-browser.
(Reading database ... 227048 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-browser_77.0.3865.120-0ubuntu1~snap1_amd64.deb
...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the chromium snap
Warning: /snap/bin was not found in your $PATH. If you've not restarted your
         session since you installed snapd, try doing that. Please see
         https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/9469 for more details.

chromium 78.0.3904.70 from Canonical✓ installed
=> Snap installation complete
Unpacking chromium-browser (77.0.3865.120-0ubuntu1~snap1) ...
Setting up chromium-browser (77.0.3865.120-0ubuntu1~snap1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
(base) keddad@keddad:~$
```

But I didn't ask it to get me chromium via snap, I wanted to get a normal .deb package. It works, after all, but it just feels wrong. If I want to get a snap, I use *snap*, not *apt*. Why such behavior is considered normal?

Comment: It's been announced:  https://ubuntu.com/blog/chromium-in-ubuntu-deb-to-snap-transition

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://askubuntu.com/a/1208738/1041922

Comment: All this is a golden opportunity to switch to Firefox.

Comment: If they  gave you a choice, you probably wouldn't do it it. So they didn't.

Comment: @Sqerstet I got upset with Chromium forcing snap, and a few other bugs which have been around for years but Chromium do not seems to care fixing them. A few months ago, I decided to switch to Firefox. I don't regret it. I still use Chromium for website testing, but Firefox is my main browser now.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, after installing the package, Chromium doesn't start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Ubuntu 19.10 it was a developer's decision. See cite from [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_19.10_New_Features):

> **Ubuntu 19.10 New Features**
>
> The Chromium browser is only available as a snap in 19.10. [This blog post has more details.](https://ubuntu.com/blog/chromium-in-ubuntu-deb-to-snap-transition)

It is normal and expected.

If you don't want to install the Chromium snap package, see [How to install Chromium without snap?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1204571/124466)

Comment: Is there a way to work around that? I tried adding the chromium PPA, but it still wants me to install snapd.

Comment: Quick search for PPAs using Y PPA Manager gives [`ppa:system76/proposed`](https://launchpad.net/~system76/+archive/ubuntu/proposed?field.series_filter=eoan) with Chromium [deb package 76.0.3809.100-1pop1](https://launchpad.net/~system76/+archive/ubuntu/proposed/+packages?field.name_filter=chromium&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) which is now outdated (it means **insecure**). So I would recommend to run fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (will be supported until 2023).

Comment: Thanks. Was able to work around my original issue needing a chromium specific browser, but will keep it in mind for future use.

Comment: It might be expected: but for sure not normal, forgive me, nobody that has not read something specific about it would expect it since the apt and apt-get man pages do no mention anything about even existing snaps.

Comment: relevant as chromium snap version has a hardcoded whitelist for xdg-open-URLs, breaking nearly everything except "http", "https", "mailto", "snap", "help", "apt", "zoommtg".
if you try to open a slack/notListed url it fails silently...
see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1776873

Comment: Linux stood for freedom. Let us chose, why throw snap at our faces?

Comment: One of the new-and-improved features of the snap-based chromium is that it is unable to access anything on the separately mounted `/opt` partition that I created on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. Until and unless the snap-based chromium allows access to partitions other than the one on which it is running, I will stick with a non-snap-based version.

Comment: according to that blog, snap was chosen because chromium has a high frequency of stable versions = more work for ubuntu team; so snap makes less work for ubuntu team, while trampling all over the users; also, they say it is great that snap installs things continuously in the background (without user knowledge or permission) so the user does not need to bother; 
if you have a deb package, you can copy it to an offline computer and install it using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` whereas snap ran a long time installing chromium and printed nothing, don't know how it compromised the system.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I disabled/removed `snap`/`snapd` from my Ubuntu and didn't want to install it again because of Chromium. Since Ubuntu and Debian are usually compatible, I installed Chromium from the Debian repositories: https://askubuntu.com/a/1206153/1038363

Comment: This is probably the best solution on here seeing as Canonical is trying to force the use of snapd after originally stating that it would never replace apt.

Comment: I tried this for a while, but it's pretty unstable -- probably because of library differences. I gave up on Ubuntu on my workstation and laptop because of this (used it on and off since 2006) and I've switched to Manjaro.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem. Wanted Chromium, but no via Snap. Found Chromium Dev PPA, works stable so far:
https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev

Comment: keep in mind that the API keys are missing and you have to add them yourself. Quoted from the repo: "Some Chromium features, including Sync, require an API key, which is not included with the packages below."

Answer (score 1):

**If you are looking for a .deb (not snap) package for Ubuntu 20.04+:**

You can get latest official .deb build for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu (latest and LTS) here:
https://launchpad.net/~phd/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-browser/

This is a PPA repository with **official Ubuntu packages** released originally for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic) and updated as soon as a new version is released.

UPDATE:

Since April 2023 Canonical does no longer provide
Chromium .deb packages for any version of Ubuntu.
Hence THIS REPOSITORY WILL NO LONGER BE UPDATED.
**You may want to switch to:**
https://freeshell.de/phd/chromium