# Special option for APT not to install via Snap

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and saw a problem while installing programs with apt. I am in a closed environment without internet but with a full copy of the Ubuntu Archives with apt-mirror.

When i want to install some programs "apt install" now uses snap to download these files..

Example:

`apt update`

`apt install chromium-browser`

Reference:
[Why apt package chromium-browser installs snap package instead?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185091/why-apt-package-chromium-browser-installs-snap-package-instead)

Is there a special switch or config to deactivate this feature? This would be really useful to me!

Comment: There is no `cromium-browser` in 20.04 apt repos.