# Why apt install snapd before installing 3rd party software?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, chromium, snap

After **installing Ubuntu 20.04** I removed snapd and want to use good old apt, but when I type:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

I get this:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
snapd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
chromium-browser snapd
```

Which installed:

1. snapd
2. and then use snapd to install chromium.

I understand that Chromium team go with snap-only approach ([snap-chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185091/why-apt-package-chromium-browser-installs-snap-package-instead), which is bad, but it's their choice), but I added chromium ppa which won't work for Ubuntu 20.04.

**Can I disable snap-only installation for apt?**

I faced several issuses with snap, eg. the current version of Chromium from snap can't open xdg-open links, while apt version on Ubuntu 18.04 can.

Comment: Not really. Apt install scripts run as root; they can do *anything* the script-writes wants...including installing snapd and a snap. The easiest way is to simply read your output so you can undo any surprises. I suppose somebody proficient with AppArmor might be able to write a rule to prevent snap installs...but a clever root script can override AppArmor, too.