# Is there an alternative to chromium-browser as a snap

Tags: chromium, snap

I would like to install chromium-browser, but since it is a snap, I cannot pre-install it.  Is there another option or way to install it the old-school way and will that be deprecated in the future?

Comment: You haven't mentioned a Ubuntu release, for some releases it's not packaged as a snap (or deb installer that then installs a snap)  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=chromium-browser

Comment: See here, read page, ect. (- for 20.04 build deps need to be fixed due to removal of python package..) https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove snap completely without losing the Chromium browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179273/how-to-remove-snap-completely-without-losing-the-chromium-browser)

Comment: Install Google Chrome from Google website. It is not open source, though.

Comment: Chromium is easily available in both snap (`chromium`) and deb packages (`chromium-browser`). Simply uninstall one and then install the other. Note that the snap is currently in testing - you may discover issues when you volunteer to help test.