# Simultaneous Downloads via APT

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu

I've been wanting this forever, but today is the first time I've ever noticed `apt` downloading more than one update at a time:
[image]

Is this now a thing? Where can I read more about the extent of this new feature? I can't seem to find out anything about this so far in my internet searches.

FYI, I'm running Kubuntu 19.10.

Comment: It only does so for downloads from different hosts. For the same host you have to use something else. See dupe.

Comment: @muru : Oh, that make sense. This is only happening because I'm running the [debian version of Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206502/256054) instead of the snap that comes with Kubuntu 19.10.