# How to get the snap-based chromium to access a separately mounted filesystem?

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, snap, restricted-access

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from the 18.04 version. Since then, the `snap`-based `chromium` browser that comes with 20.04 is unable to access any items in the `/opt` partition which I have separately mounted on my system.

If I go to the trouble of installing a non-`snap`-based version of `chromium`, I do not have this problem under 20.04.

I'm not sure, but I think this problem with accessing filesystems outside of the one on which a snap program is running might be present in all `snap`-based software, not just `chromium`.

How can I get `chromium` and all other `snap`-based programs to see ***all*** the filesystems that I have mounted?

Thank you very much.

**PS**: On my system, `/opt` is mounted via the following line within `/etc/fstab` ...

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /opt ext4 defaults,auto 0 0
```

... where the x's take the place of an actual, valid UUID.

**PPS**: All non-`snap`-based software on my system has no trouble whatsoever in accessing anything on this `/opt` partition.

**PPPS**: The suggested solution in the referenced article does not solve my problem, because I would have to change my system around (changing mounts, paths, scripts, *etc*.), simply to get this crippled, `snap`-based `chromium` to work as it used to work before. My goal is to not change my long-standing system setup at all, but rather, to simply install a version of `chromium` which can run in the same way that I have been running it for years. The answer I have now posted shows the way I learned how to do this. After discovering that method to eliminate the `snap`-based `chromium` and replace it with the traditional version, it took me no longer than 10 minutes to replace `chromium` so that everything runs like it always has been able to run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give snaps access to /somedir](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried uninstalling the `chromium` `snap` and reinstalling, both with `--devmode` and with `--classic`. In both cases, I still couldn't access my `/opt` partition.

Comment: b.t.w. as I said in my answer, classic confinement has to be supported. It is not for Chromium, so that is not an option. ("Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap chromium")

Comment: Yes, I know what you said about it not working for classic confinement. I just tried it anyway, just in case, and not surprisingly, what you wrote is correct.

Comment: Update: see "NEW INFORMATION" which I added to my accepted answer. I discovered a way to run chromium from the original snap bundle, but without any containment restrictions.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NEW INFORMATION**: I still stand by my opinion (now in the section prefaced with "MY ORIGINAL ANSWER (trimmed down)", below) that Ubuntu should offer both `snap` and non-`snap` versions of its packages instead of forcing us all to use the `snap` versions. However, I also discovered how to bypass the containment restrictions of the existing `snap`-based package:

If the standard Ubuntu `snap`-based `chromium` package is installed, we can run the program like this:

```
/snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome [ ... args ... ]
```

This bypasses the containment restrictions.

**MY ORIGINAL ANSWER *(trimmed down)***:

*(Editorializing deleted)* I have followed a suggestion in the following discussion which explains how to disable the crippled, `snap`-based `chromium` and to install a version which offers full capabilities, including the ability to access the filesystems which I want to access:
[How to remove snap completely without losing the Chromium browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179273/how-to-remove-snap-completely-without-losing-the-chromium-browser/1200343#1200343)

I didn't remove `snap` completely ... all I did was perform the part of this that was suggested by the user called "eitch" (around 75% down towards the bottom of that discussion). Using this non-`snap` version of `chromium` solves my problem.

*(Editorializing deleted)*

**UPDATE**: Yet another solution would be for Ubuntu to offer both `snap`-based and non-`snap`-based packages for software such as `chromium`, so that each of us users could individually decide whether we want the full, traditional functionality of the given packages, or whether we want to install `snap`-based versions of the packages which make use of containment and might therefore have lesser functionality than the older versions. *(Editorializing deleted)*

**ANOTHER UPDATE**: I have now investigated this behavior under `flatpak` and `appimage`, and programs that are run via these services seem to have no trouble accessing all of the partitions and files on my system that are accessible via the command line. This containment restriction which cripples `chromium` apparently only applies only to `snap`.

Comment: Neat and to me very unexpected finding. It indeed appears to fundamentally resolve your issue. Would be good to know why it works this way. If you edit the question and remove the ballast and personal opinion, I will upvote the answer.

Comment: It appears you are bypassing "snap" and directly running the mounted binary code. So that probably does not establish the sandboxing. Again, great find!

Comment: I think I understand why it would work this way. The `snap`-based containment is enforced via `snap` and `snapd` by means data which exists inside of `/snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/SNAP-PACKAGE`, and it sets up a `fuse`-based enviroment based upon all of this where certain filesystems are available and others are not. The executable within that directory tree is just a "normal" executable.

Comment: I also believe it is misguided to apply this kind of containment to a general-purpose piece of software like `chromium`. It makes sense, for example, that the `certbot` `snap` could enforce containment, given that it's a focused, special-purpose utility. However, all containment does for a general-purpose browser is to take away features that are intrinsic to that kind of software, and it thereby makes users' lives more complicated. Yes, this comment is editorializing, and as you can see, I've now removed a lot of the editorializing from my original answer.

Answer (score 5):

Snaps, by design, are sandboxed. A snap can be connected to "[interfaces](https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-interfaces)" to allow them to do specific things. No interfaces are foreseen to allow a snap to access system folders. Even if such interface would exist, the packagers of Chromium still would need to enable connecting the interface to the snap.

In general, you can have a snap access a specific folder (a "separately mounted file system" is, once it is mounted, just a folder structure) by a `mount --bind` of that folder under a folder where the snap has access.

Some snaps can be installed in "classic" mode. "Classic mode" removes all sandboxing, and hence all security. Installing in classic mode is only possible if the snap has been prepared for that. Publishing a classic snap requires manual approval of the snap store maintainers. Therefore, many snaps cannot be installed in classic mode.

Perhaps, however, you should reconsider your workflow: do you really need your browser to access `/opt`?

Comment: Yes, I need my browser to access `/opt`. I have procedures which depend on URL's such as `file:///opt/path/to/somewhere`. I don't want to restructure my entire Ubuntu filesystem setup and/or a number of scripts and procedures that have been in use for a couple years, just because it was decided to only offer `chromium` as a `snap` nowadays.

Comment: I wouldn't mind the decision to offer a `snap`-based version of `chromium` and other software if non-`snap` versions of these same items were also offered. I now understand and support Linux Mint's decision to not support `snap` packages without the user's prior consent. See this article: https://www.ghacks.net/2020/06/16/linux-mint-20-will-block-ubuntu-snap-by-default/

Comment: I forgot to mention above that I tried `mount --bind /opt /home/myusername/mnt/opt` (after creating `~/mnt/opt`) with the `snap`-based `chromium`, but `file:///home/myusername/mnt/opt/path/to/somewhere` just hung forever in `snap`-based `chromium`, despite the fact that I could easily `cd` into that directory and access anything I want there from the command line.

Comment: You have to mount in a folder where the snap has access, i.e. under the chromium's snap or if the document interface is enabled, under Documents, Movies, etc. Even that solution will require you to change your paths. See the question of which I in the end marked this question as duplicate: essentially with snap, you currently cannot use any path you want. By the way, this is not at all related to you mounting a separate file system.

Comment: Yes, that would require me to change paths. And it would also require a `mount --bind` for every user on the system who utilizes the existing software that is `chromium`-based. As I mentioned in my "PPPS" (which references the duplicate post), that post does not address the issues that I need to solve. It turns out that `chromium` has been crippled in order to run in the `snap` world, and I therefore disabled its `snap` version and replaced it with the "traditional" one. This allows my system to continue to run the way it has been running for years for myself and my users.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but my answer is a.f.a.i.k.  the current state, even if this answer is disappointing to you. This answer and the posts we find elsewhere suggests your issue can currently not be solved with the snap version. Disappointing as it may be.

Comment: Understood. Thankfully, my solution of replacing the `snap` version of `chromium` with the non-`snap` version solved my problem relatively quickly and easily. IMO, certain software should not be made into a `snap` package in the first place. Anyway, thank you for all your feedback and explanation.

Comment: Update: see "NEW INFORMATION" which I added to my accepted answer. I discovered a way to run `chromium` from the original `snap` bundle, but without any containment restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

For similar reasons, I gave up on the snap-based Chromium and use Google Chrome instead (which comes as a .deb package). I can only recommend that.

Comment: This is the sane answer. Snap version breaks too much, has random hidden paths that only the developers at snap know about, ties your hands in so many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Start root shell by

```
env SHELL=/bin/bash sudo -s
```

Thereafter, to be able to use data under */opt* in Chromium, do

```
snap connect chromium:removable-media
mkdir -p /media/opt
echo "/opt    /media/opt    none    bind" >>/etc/fstab
mount -a
exit
```

Then you should be able to use */opt* via */media/opt* in Chromium.

If you need only temporary access, replace the  `echo` line and the `mount` line above by

```
mount --bind /opt /media/opt
```

To be able to use possible submounts, too, use `rbind` instead of `bind`.

You can use **all** mounted filesystems via */mnt/r/* by running

```
mount --rbind / /mnt/r
```

(as superuser) if directory */mnt/r* exists.

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264488/111181) for instructions on how to unmount an *rbind* mount.

Note that there may be security risks in mounting all the extra filesystems.

See [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/removable-media-interface) for information about the removable-media interface.

Comment: Thank you very much. This would get me only part of the way towards what I want. There are scripts. utilities, and user procedures which all reference `/opt`, and they would all have to be changed to refer to `/media/opt`, simply so that the Ubuntu version of `chromium` could be utilized. This is still needless work, IMO, since it's easier to simply bypass the `snap` version of that program altogether and use the non-`snap` version which I have now already installed.

Comment: @HippoMan no, you can continue to use `/opt` like before even if you do the additional mounting.

Comment: Hmm ... I think I see what you mean. If the original `/opt` in fstab is mounted to `/media/opt` instead, then the addtional bind mount that you describe would also allow it to be referred to as `/opt`. I guess that `chromium` could then also see it as `/opt` without having to refer to it there as `/media/opt`, correct?

Comment: The original mount applies, but the additional mount makes the tree available on /media/opt, too. I guess not, but you could experiment.