# Error unistalling Snap version of Chromium

Tags: kubuntu, snap, chromium, deb

I am running Kubuntu 20.10 on a Samsung Chromebook.

Since I was having problems saving files with the Snap version of Chromium, I installed the Deb version and that works fine for me.

I tried to remove the snap with  `sudo snap remove chromium` But I got:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks: - 
Save data of snap "chromium" in automatic snapshot set #1 
(cannot create archive: tar: common/chromium/Profile 1/Extension State/002511.log: file changed as we read it (and 0 more))
```

Can anyone tell me how to safely remove the Snap Chromium **without** affecting the Deb version?

EDIT 17 April 21
I found an answer that worked for me here: [How to remove snap completely without losing the Chromium browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179273)
As mentioned by @ʇsәɹoɈ.

```
snap remove chromium
```

then

```
sudo apt purge chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer that worked for me here: [How to remove snap completely without losing the Chromium browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179273) As mentioned by @ʇsәɹoɈ.

```
snap remove chromium
```

then

```
sudo apt purge chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver
```

Had to remove <chromium_chromium.desktop> from </home/user/.local/share/applications> to get rid of the App in the Application Launcher also removed an empty folder called  in </home/user/snap>.

My Deb Chromium if working fine and the Snap version is gone.