# Install Chrome on ubuntu/debian with arm64

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, arm64

I'm trying to install chrome using the commands below:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
apt update && apt install -y google-chrome-stable --no-install-recommends
```

I get the following error:

```
Get:4 https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1811 B]
Fetched 1811 B in 0s (4467 B/s)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
All packages are up to date.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
```

Anyone have any ideas why this doesn't work for me? Could it be that Google chrome package is not available for my system:

```
root@xxx:/# dpkg --print-architecture
arm64
root@xxx:/# uname -a
Linux xxxx 5.11.0-1021-oracle #22~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 22 21:42:24 UTC 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux

root@65653cdc2f7b:/# cat /etc/debian_version
11.2
```

Comment: Thanks @Terrance - Updated the url as per your suggestion but I still get the same error..

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details; your provided output from /etc/ are incomplete or vague,  but don't forget not all *amd64* packages are available for *arm64*

Comment: Oops, I missed the aarch64 part.  Chrome is not available for aarch64.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is expected. Google Chrome is only packaged for amd64, and is not available for ARM.
You can use Chromium instead. It is the free and open source browser, on which Chrome is based.

You can remove the Chrome repository, and install chromium with

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

This will install the snap chromium package. If you want a pure apt version, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179273/how-to-remove-snap-completely-without-losing-the-chromium-browser/1206502#1206502) answer.

---

Google removed synchronization features from Chromium. If you need synchronization, use Firefox instead.

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Alternatively, ask Google to release Chrome for ARM or to fix sync in Chromium, if you really need it.

Comment: Man how annoying to not have a arm version in chrome

Comment: @JamieHutber Things may soon change with powerful arm computers like the new Mac and Microsoft Dev Kit 2023. Till then, keep annoying google with support requests of Chrome arm version for Linux :)